# Global minimum for $\frac{2(q - 1)(q^k + 1)}{q^{k+1} + q - 1}$, if $q \geq 5$ and $k \geq 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, discrete-optimization, wolfram-alpha

Let $q$ be a prime number, and let $k$ be an integer.

**THE PROBLEM**

> Does the function
> $$f(q,k) = \frac{2(q - 1)(q^k + 1)}{q^{k+1} + q - 1}$$
> have a global minimum, if $q \geq 5$ and $k \geq 1$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

I tried asking [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize%202%28q%20-%201%29%28q%5Ek%20%2B%201%29%2F%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29%20%2B%20q%20-%201%29%20for%20q%20%3E%3D%205%2C%20k%20%3E%3D%201), it was unable to find a global minimum for $f(q,k)$ in the domain $q \geq 5$ and $k \geq 1$.

I then computed the partial derivatives (still using WolframAlpha):

[Partial derivative with respect to $q$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Differentiate%202%28q%20-%201%29%28q%5Ek%20%2B%201%29%2F%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29%20%2B%20q%20-%201%29%20with%20respect%20to%20q)
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial q} f(q,k) = \frac{2q^{k-1}\bigg(q^{k+1} - k(q - 1) + q\bigg)}{\bigg(q^{k+1} + q - 1\bigg)^2} > 0$$

[Partial derivative with respect to $k$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Differentiate%202%28q%20-%201%29%28q%5Ek%20%2B%201%29%2F%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29%20%2B%20q%20-%201%29%20with%20respect%20to%20k)
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial k} f(q,k) = -\frac{2(q-1){q^k}\log(q)}{\bigg(q^{k+1} + q - 1\bigg)^2} < 0.$$

Does this mean that we can have (say)
$$f(q,k) \geq f(5,1) = \frac{48}{29} \approx 1.65517?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{2}{f(q,k)}=\frac{q^{k+1}+q-1}{(q-1)(q^k+1)}=1+\frac{1}{q-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{q^k+1}\right)$$ is strictly increasing in $k$, so it can't have a global *maximum*, hence $f(q,k)$ can't have a global minimum.

Comment: Indeed!  Thank you, @metamorphy!  =)